# How to write 1, 2, ... as a subscript to a letter?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I have two `theta` angles, one is `\theta -1`, other one is `\theta -2`. How can I write that properly? I want to give numbers to the thetas, putting the numbers at the bottom right end of the letter.

Comment: Please consider giving a valid reason after you downvote the questions. Downvoting beginner questions might be OK for SO but not for TeX.SE

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is called subscript and is activated (in math mode) with `_`:

```
\theta_1
\theta_2
```

You might (should) be  interested in further reading, I recommend the [Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort) (surely available in [*your* language](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort)).

### [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) (some examples)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}\noindent
\verb|\theta_1|                    gives: \( \theta_1    \)                 \\
\verb|\theta_2|                    gives: \( \theta_2    \)                 \\
\verb|\theta_12|                   gives: \( \theta_12   \)                 \\
\verb|\theta_{12}|                 gives: \( \theta_{12} \)                 \\
\verb|\theta^1|                    gives: \( \theta^1    \)                 \\
\verb|\theta^1_2|                  gives: \( \theta^1_2  \)                 \\
\verb|\theta_1^2|                  gives: \( \theta_1^2  \)                 \\
\verb|\theta_{x,y}^{\frac{1}{2}}|  gives: \( \theta_{x,y}^{\frac{1}{2}}  \) \\
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: @HasanFerit I've updated my answer with some examples and a text recommendation. I seriously advise you to read some introduction because this is a basic topic. Nonetheless, you're [welcome](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to ask _any_ question. :)

Comment: this is great..! i will check the website. thanks again.