# How would one have an expression for an exponent?

Tags: equations

How can I write `2^((n-1)/3)` or anything similar in `LaTeX`? I am new to the whole thing, but I tried giving it a shot and it doesn't look the way I want it too. It looks like I am taking the 2 to the power of parenthesis, which is silly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A notation such as the one obtained by `$2^{(n-1)/3}$` is rather common.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Take a look at [How to write 1, 2, ... as a subscript to a letter?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77924) and get used to `{ }` which groups `(n-1)/2` so that the whole fraction gets “superscripted.”

Comment: The key to remember in LaTeX is that braces are the (unseen) grouping symbols.  Therefore, after the ^ character, whatever is enclosed in braces {} will be the exponential

Comment: `(n-1)/2` is an *expression*, not an *equation* (despite what MS Word says).  But if you had an equation such as `x=3`, you could still form the expression `$2^{x=3}$`.

Comment: In this simple case you can also use `$\sqrt[3]{2^{n-1}}$`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just to give a little closure...

Depends on what you want.  As egreg said, you can go by

`$2^{(n-1)/3}$`

...or you could also try using `\frac{numerator}{denominator}`, as in

`$2^{\frac{n-1}{3}}$`